# tilt of object from the normals

Tags: math, angle, normals

I have a flat object (not totally flat (let's say in range of 25µm)) which I measured two times (The measuring concept is not important here) with applying a tilt between the two times.

I have the normals in each point of the surface and I want from these normals to know the tilt that has been applied.

My approach was to calculate the average normal of each one and then calculate the angle between the normals.

Could you please suggest for me another solution or confirm mine?!

Many thanks in advance

Comment: what is wrong with your solution?

Comment: If it was a flat object totally, I wouldn't have asked at all. But because it is in range of 25µm, I want to be sure that the solution is still valid under any circumistances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your solution should work**

- but you have to measure normals:
- **evenly distributed** on the **whole area**
- or **always** on the **same points of the object** (which is not the case I assume)
- if this condition is not true it could lower the accuracy a lot
- Now to be sure we are talking about the same thing:

[image]

- red vectors 1,2 are the average normals
- **angle between them is not tilt !!!**
- but angle between plates (in combination around two axises)
- so if you want just tilt in one axis you have to **project** these normals
- **onto plane** you want the tilt be in (blue vectors 1,2 on the right let them be n1,n2)
- angle between these vectors is the tilt

  ```
  tilt = acos( (n1.n2)/(|n1|.|n2|) )
  ```

**Another method**

- without knowing the measurement possibilities
- and object shape is hard to suggest another measurement method to validate yours.
- anyway if you **can measure distances** you can for **plate-like objects** do this:

[image]

- so measure a0,a1,b
- compute ang

  ```
  ang=atan2(a0-a1,b)
  ```
- do this also for the second measurement and then:

  ```
  tilt = ang2-ang1
  ```

[notes]

- texts on the image are small so zoom it or download the image and view in image viewer if needed
- if tilt plane is one of the base planes (xy,xz or yz) then just ignore the unused axis coordinate

Comment: You talked about the proejection of the vectors onto a plane but if I want to project that means I have to know the angle which I don't know but Your answer was quite enough to assure my answer.

Thanks for your solution!